# material angular with angular 4 in production

Tags: angular, material-design, version, production

I  took a look at this page https://material.angular.io.

Material angular component's and functionnalities seem awesome.  but they are still in beta (2.0.0.beta8  according to  https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/material)

So should we use it  on production project?

Answer (score 1):

That is mostly a personal choice. I use it in production. There may be changes to the api but if the component works for you it isn't going anywhere. Even if the api changes you can reference the old package until you are ready to upgrade.

Again, there may be changes. But, personally I happily use it in production with no problems.

Comment: thank you for your anwser Mgm87.   Do you know Ionic or PrimeNG librairies? If so what was  your reason to choose Material Angular and not primeNg or Ionic or for exemple http://ionicmaterial.com/  ?

Comment: I really like PrimeNG and haven't used Ionic. I actually use both material and PrimeNG in the same project because material's sidenav component worked so nicely. That's the beauty of angular tree-shaking, I can use multiple ui frameworks if needed with minimal bloat and no styling conflicts. This is only true as long as you are doing an AOT build.

Answer (score 0):

I use it in production as well. Just make sure you have a fixed version of your dependency in your *package.json* file.

Otherwise, it may auto-update to a newer one if you rebuild your app (which could break things).
In your case:

```
"@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.8"
```